# Prove that |O(2n)-O(n)|=O(n)

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove that statement with the defenition of big O

```
    |O(2n)-O(n)|=O(n)
```

Does it can be proven? or not?

if i can, so how..in which way? i tried almost everything

Comment: Could you write down your definition of $O(n)$? It will ensure we all use the same.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $O(2n) = O(n)$, as constants are dropped with asymptotics. Remember that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if and only if $|f(n)| \leq C * |g(n)|$, for a constant $C$ and $n \geq n_{0}$. So trivially, $n = O(2n) = O(n)$. It's also easy to see that $f(n) = O(f(n))$.

So let $f(n) \in O(2n)$ and $g(n) \in O(n)$. So $f(n) \leq 2Cn$ and $g(n) \leq Kn$. Subtracting them, you get $(2C-k)n$. That's clearly $O(n)$.

Comment: Depending on the definition of $O$, you should have $|f(n)|\le 2Cn$ and $|g(n)| \le Kn$. So $|(f-g)(n)| \le (2C+k)n$. It's still $O(n)$, but one needs to be careful about subtracting $O$ things - they don't cancel just because of the visible minus sign.